# how to disable hotkeys in chromium

Tags: google-chrome, java, chromium

Everyone i am a system administrator in a company.

I am making a package of chromium 39 portable and jportable to run a web application.

I am looking for a way to disable right click, ctrl f4, etc... hotkeys in the chromium browser. Can someone help me please.

thanks

Comment: Trying to restrict people from right-clicking is always a losing proposition because: i) it irritates your users, ii) it's their system and they can overcome your JS if they really want to anyway. If you really want to then there are tutorials on the web, but I would highly recommend that you re-think your approach. Edit: Perhaps kiosk mode might help you accomplish what you want.